# How to stop tracing (safely) in Elixir using the BEAM VM's tracing functions?

Tags: erlang, elixir, trace

I have been gathering data using the functionality provided by `:erlang.trace` in an Elixir program. By specify an option of `{:tracer, some_pid}` I can have another process get traces for everything currently going on in a process. The output of this is really useful.

The issue I am running into is how to stop tracing the process without crashing the VM. The documentation for `:erlang.trace` is here

http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#trace-3

My presumption is that I could set `How` to `false`  and set my options to `[:all]` to disable everything.

Here is the example program I have

```
defmodule Example do
  def simple_tracer() do
    receive do 
      x -> IO.inspect(x); simple_tracer()
    end
  end

  def fancy_tracer() do
    receive do
      x -> IO.puts "fancy!" <> inspect(x); fancy_tracer
    end
  end
end

simple = spawn_link(&Example.simple_tracer/0)
fancy = spawn_link(&Example.fancy_tracer/0)

#Tell BEAM to trace everything
:erlang.trace_pattern(
{:_,:_,:_},
true,
[:local]
)

#Tell BEAM to trace this processs, but send the result to the simple tracer

:erlang.trace(self(),
true,
[:send,
:receive,
:procs,
:ports,
:garbage_collection,
:monotonic_timestamp,
:set_on_first_spawn,
:set_on_first_link,
:call,
:return_to,
{:tracer, simple},
:arity])

IO.inspect Enum.map([1,2,3,4,5], fn x -> :math.sqrt(x) end)

#Tell BEAM to stop tracing 
:erlang.trace(self(), false, [:all])

#This should not show up in the trace

IO.inspect Enum.map([3,7,11,101], fn x -> :math.sqrt(x) end)

#Tell BEAM to start tracing again

:erlang.trace(self(),
true,
[:send,
:receive,
:procs,
:ports,
:garbage_collection,
:monotonic_timestamp,
:set_on_first_spawn,
:set_on_first_link,
:call,
:return_to,
{:tracer, fancy},
:arity])


IO.inspect Enum.map([10,20,30,40,50], fn x -> :math.sqrt(x) end)
```

The program uses two seperate processes to trace the main one. Or at least it attempts to. Here is output I get when I run it:

```
[ericu-destroyer-of-worlds] ~$ elixir ~/elixir_tracing.ex 
[1.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.7320508075688772, 2.0, 2.23606797749979]
{:trace_ts, #PID<0.71.0>, :call, {Enum, :map, 2}, -576460751827716034}
Segmentation fault
```

As best I can tell the call to `:erlang.trace(self(), false, [:all])` results in a segmentation fault. All I am trying to do is disable all the tracing so that the process `simple` stops receiving the traces.

**Update**

A commenter indicated they could not reproduce the crash.

I tried the code above on the following version and it *crashed*.

```
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Elixir 1.3.1
```

I then ran it on this version and it *did not crash*.

```
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Elixir 1.2.5
```

Why does this code crash on one version and not another?

Comment: You shouldn't get a segfault even if the arguments are wrong. This looks like a bug in Erlang. What OS are you on? Your code appears to run fine on OSX 10.11 for me (I get several lines of output, no segfault, and exit code 0).

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is the operating system I am using. Versions are "erts-8.0" and "elixir 1.3.0"